# Facebook Graph API: Can't get all friends of a user with a graph v1.0 (old) facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

We have a facebook app which surely with open graph 1.0 (app created before May 1th, 2014, and can be  switch to v1.0 with graph API explorer). The problem is, we can't get all friends from user from /me/friends - the API just behaved like 2.0 - return friends who also install this facebook app.

We heard rumors that if someone (app administrator) once call the open graph API v2.0, it will be switch to v2.0 and never come back. Is this true?

Comment: No, but apps which were dormant were also switched to use v2.0 or higher - was this app actually in use or just one which was created before April 30th 2014?

Comment: I am sure those apps was created before April 30th 2014. But yes, we didn't use it immediately (login/etc.) so it may be rated as dormant by facebook. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lgy, we created these facebook apps before April 30th 2014 but didn't activate them (login/etc.), so they were switch to v2.0 by facebook.